# asynchronous imageview in blackberry

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, java-me, asynchronous, encode

I'm developing blackberry application for OS 5.0 and later. Using xml parsing I have to display data on perticular screen. From the backend I'm getting one url which will be display in screen. I have successfully encoded image from the live url display it.

It is time consuming task to encode image from the live url and display it rather other data parse quickly but I want display all data quickly in that screen without image and the image will be display when it will be encoded successfully till progress indicator will be display on image place.

So, how to manage that? Is it possible using thread to handle it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes image should be handled in it's own thread. I suggest you start working on that and paste the code here if you need further help.

Comment: if you have any example regarding same